# combine multiple results and pick the non-null value , or assign null if all results return null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting

I have a view where the the records are like this:

[image]

I want to query and return the result like this for a report (Do not have any BI tools available, only using SSMS) :

[image]

I have tried :

```
select distinct A.Document_Title, A.First_Reviewer, A.Second_Reviewer, A.Third_Reviewer,
(select B.First_review from View as B where B.Title = A.Title) as First_Review,
(select B.Second_review from View as B where B.Title = A.Title) as Second_Review,
(select B.Third_review from View as B where B.Title = A.Title) as Third_Review
From
View A
```

I am getting error because my sub query returns more than one result, I have also tried using Coalesce but realized that is used to combine multiple columns.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I removed the plsql tag based on the preponderance of evidence.

Comment: There is a slight curiosity in the logic used here.  I'd take a copy of the view, and edit it to return exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only need a `group by`:

```
select a.document_title,
       a.first_reviewer, a.second_reviewer, a.third_reviewer,
       max(first_review) as first_review,
       max(second_review) as second_review,
       max(third_review) as third_review
from viewA a
group by a.document_title, a.first_reviewer, a.second_reviewer;
```

Your view is probably poorly formed.  This aggregation should probably occur in the view.  If it uses `pivot`, then the query probably left in an unnecessary column.